# How to add extra html attribute in struts 1 html taglib?

Tags: java, css, struts-1

How can I add `autocomplete="off"` standard html attribute to my input tag in struts 1?

my input:

```
<html:text property="appUser.username" size="21" maxlength="50"/>
```

A javascript solution is not appropriate only a CSS or struts 1 solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable autocomplete for Struts tags(HTML:text)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322853/how-to-disable-autocomplete-for-struts-tagshtmltext)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom tld overriding struts html taglib. Get the original struts-html.tld, copy it as struts-html-autocomplete.tld  in your tags folder. Add into **form tag**:

```
<tag>
    <name>form</name>
     ...
    <attribute>
        <name>autocomplete</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
    ....
</tag>
```

In web.xml define the new tld:

```
<jsp-config>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>html</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/struts-html-autocomplete.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```